Connection problem between ROS2 in WSL2 and Unity in Windows
I'm trying to build a system which is composed of Unity which has a ros2-for-unity in Windows11 and ROS2 in WSL2.
However, I can not pub/sub between ROS2 in WSL2 and Unity in Windows.
Ros2-for-unity worked in Windows11 (I can pub/sub internally in Unity) and ROS2 totally worked in WSL2 (I can pub/sub internally in WSL2), so I think the problem is caused by the network setting between WSL2 and Windows.
Is there anything I have to write in wslconfig or other files?
Are there anyone who tried this setting??
Thank you for your help.
I put the link which could be related to this issue.

https://github.com/RobotecAI/ros2-for-unity/issues/76

Suggest to change Cyclone DDS


https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/discussions/10614



Ok, now I understand the problem is caused by ROS DOMAIN ID.
In ros2-for-unity, how can I define ROS DOMAIN ID ??

Please [edit] and update your question with the info in your comment and any other info that may be useful. Please don't put additional info or questions in the comments section, that is not what it is for. Thanks.
